# Swift Dismiss Mail Controller from Slide Menu

Tags: ios, swift, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I'm having trouble with MFMailComposer. I've followed this guide for iOS Developers using the example [Swift Code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/).

I've also taken a look at the following similar questions on this site:

[swift - dismissing mail view controller from Sprite Kit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36415591/swift-dismissing-mail-view-controller-from-sprite-kit)

[MFMailComposeViewController in Swift does not dismiss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24341881/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-in-swift-does-not-dismiss)

Linked Frameworks & Libraries: MessagesUI.framework

```
import MessageUI

class FHCLLeftMenuViewController: FHBaseViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate
```

When I tap the Support text in the left slide menu of my app, the Mail app comes up, I compose an email and click send. The email appears in my inbox but the controller is not dismissing itself after sending the mail. This also occurs when I attempt to delete the draft and I have to close the app and relaunch it.

```
        case kFHCLMenuTagSupport:
        //PT DashBoard

        if !MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
            print("Mail services are not available")
            return
        }

        let composeVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
        composeVC.mailComposeDelegate = self

        // Configure the fields of the interface.
        composeVC.setToRecipients(["support@example.com"])
        composeVC.setSubject("Client Support")
        composeVC.setMessageBody("Some text here.", isHTML: false)



        // Present the view controller modally.
        self.presentViewController(composeVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

        func mailComposeController(controller: MFMailComposeViewController,
                                   didFinishWithResult result: MFMailComposeResult, error: NSError?) {
            // Check the result or perform other tasks.

            // Dismiss the mail compose view controller.
            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

        }
        break
```

I've also tried this variation to return to the main dashboard of the app with the same result:

```
     case kFHCLMenuTagSupport:
        //PT DashBoard
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Client", bundle: nil)

        // Create View Controllers
        let mainPage:FHClientDashBoardViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("FHClientDashBoardViewController") as! FHClientDashBoardViewController
        let mainPageNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainPage)



        if !MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
            print("Mail services are not available")
            return
        }

        let composeVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
        composeVC.mailComposeDelegate = self

        // Configure the fields of the interface.
        composeVC.setToRecipients(["support@example.com"])
        composeVC.setSubject("Client Support")
        composeVC.setMessageBody("Some text here.", isHTML: false)



        // Present the view controller modally.
        self.presentViewController(composeVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

        func mailComposeController(controller: MFMailComposeViewController,
                                   didFinishWithResult result: MFMailComposeResult, error: NSError?) {
            // Check the result or perform other tasks.

            // Dismiss the mail compose view controller.
            // self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
            self.mm_drawerController.setCenterViewController(mainPageNav, withCloseAnimation: true, completion: nil)
        }

        break
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to dismiss the `MFMailComposeViewController` or `FHCLLeftMenuViewController`?

Answer (score 0):

The `dismissViewControllerAnimated(_:completion:)` function dismisses the view controller that calls that function. In this case, since you are calling it on `self`, it attempts to dismiss `FHCLLeftMenuViewController`. This can be easily fixed by calling `dismissViewControllerAnimated(_:completion:)` on the `MFMailComposeViewController` instead.

To do this, simply replace your `mailComposeController(controller:didFinishWithResult:error:)` function with the following (it also appears this way in Apple's own documentation):

```
func mailComposeController(controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWithResult result: MFMailComposeResult, error: NSError?) {
    // Check the result or perform other tasks.

    // Dismiss the mail compose view controller.
    controller.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The tip from the post didn't work but it was something in the code of how the menu was set up (not because of the recommendation). After some thought, I came up with a workaround which worked better. Since the program has both a IM message system and a email system for support I did the following:

1.) Linked the Support button in the menu to a new view controller & storyboard.

2.) Added the option of contact via 1:1 messenger or email support

For some reason, when not trying to dismiss directly from the slide menu, the compose mail view was dismissed from the view controller. Not the most elegant solution but it worked.